# Why does `instanceof` cause type information loss in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, type-inference, instanceof

From a conversation started on GitHub:

```
class A<T> {
  constructor(public value: T) {}
}

const wrap = <T,>(value: T) => {
  if (value instanceof A) {
    return value
  }

  return undefined;
};
```

The return value type `T & A<any>` is causing type information loss

```
type testType1 = (A<number> & A<any>)['value']; // any
```

Why is the intersection not done with `unknown` as a filler instead of `any`?

```
type testType0 = (A<number> & A<unknown>)['value']; // number
```

On GitHub, Ryan said:

> because you're assuming that any `A` is an `A<T>`, even though this isn't true.

But I feel like its the actual opposite. `A<number>` is an `A` (not `A` an `A<T>`) so I believe that we can safely say that the return value is `A<number> & A<unknown>`.

I don't understand why this is not the case. If `A<number>` is `A<any|unknown>`, why can't we safely say that the return value is `A<number>`?

And then, I think that some intersections should also be avoided as they can also cause indirect metadata loss

```
const a = wrap('hello')!;

const value = a.value; // any
```

Things like this should not be possible IMO. Because we know for sure that this can never ever happen, type `string` is not an `object`. And that is true for any primitive. Imagine that we pass a union now:

```
const a = wrap('hello' as A<number> | string)!;

const value = a.value; // any again
```

But we can say for sure that at least one of them will pass, but `any` is causing problems again. [I wrote an emulation of `instanceOf` that aims to resolve all these points](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.0.2#code/PQKhFgCgAIWhBANgSwIYGdoBcD20DGATgKapbHAAmx6RyARsdKtAAb6IbqtSzQACAB1SFUAW2gAFaMiyZ8OAHboshAK75chaMNFji5Qul5whI8dABK2ABZMc9AFbFNMrASUr1m4zFMksNUJlNg4uHj9gKCwAT0EmAGFOdHQAHl4paGIAD3JFSkwSVEolRBjoNUUAa0UcAHdFAG0AXWgAXmgiksUyiurahpaAGgzrDsqa%20sUoAD526ABvDMViOugACgA6bZEAc3QALikASiPLAG4oAF9LyChQCD9oAHEDWyZWB2dNVhllLFQinwTFi8WgOAAZsxQsluCYBLoLAlYCBQcRIWACLD4fwAkEQp8nC4sBFYFFIGjoABJf6A4EAeQhqWROTyBWgSS4czaGRZuWI%20UwnJSqS6pXKEwGTWaQz%20EOI2npMwyAH5oPSMkcVgA3BW3e5geEAUVyolcWDsOhE7khbAAqr8LWRoGIyPg7JhWABZUmmRESO3YPCss3uCGEHBiHH%206BeoPQdDERDE6B1WQ2HF44KYSrIJQmcmUgDKSeJqTtsvg3IygdZAvZ8FV0DtmugOr1UANjz4dqwyBQsVszuIYjUnHImEBlBkYkEEd1mAtTEYNlQ2rz2ltrGQtKBxEZvoR5gk8D%20KjpILw7pcVWYu1QO5U0ePHKxXHjjGwNHI07TFszBj4p6p4AGQcr6hZxEwAByIgRnUqTwLKfJskKsLVjAzCKOUdaCggTYlsmmipDS557oyzIzJWyqYUckpTFk-J4Y2mHQNAaqgdSu4MkyCQ0WxbFHIRZZIVxZE8ZRMz6pADzwl6OAkNgUEALToKg8pZAAjmoyDaqgyaKDaULbtx%204QoeZh6LYO67GeAJ7vG174LeqD3o%20WDPlZwryLCH4gt%20xC-umBZQAo-x2RejLzIhyGMahHLoesGQWjZRxIbysJHAkIyQKc1mKLZyCYLBhDwTFHLcnMSysZ0gHBPlhWmba3m3DcnaQGEKQIKkAAqVUZGFXgaFo6yCGo9AoPg0B6YgajEEcPXHIsVzXO1g3uHUoiCNFPVDDM6wzXNC1LW0-WYcgULrO5kUQgd%20lzZWxxLdVAm1YE9WHcQtxsStdyYVmih9NQEI7oFrXSetzAAAzzJtqCCOsADkdiIIgOCI8cACEtyQ6gACMsNbesKxrPA6wACwAExPTjnjuKglOE-DSMo2jiPMJg8CpIoahiIwhBzAAPgmqg2cctxAA)

Comment: You're referring to a conversation on GitHub and mentioning people by name.  Could you link to this conversation?  I assume that "Ryan" is [this Ryan](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh), so if he says something about TS it has a good chance of being true, and it would be useful to see the context in which he says these things.

Comment: Okay I found it, [microsoft/TypeScript#40436](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40436).  I think the answer to this question as stated would be in [microsoft/TypeScript#17473](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17473) or [microsoft/typeScript#](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28560) or [microsoft/TypeScript#30161](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30161). Not sure it belongs here though.